# jsp page doesn't get the data from mysql

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, netbeans

I'm facing problem to view data from my database in mysql using a jsp page in netbeans.
here's my code in the jsp page :

```
<%@page import="javax.swing.JOptionPane"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DatabaseMetaData"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.ArrayList" import="gettingItem.Item"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>   
        <h2>Home Page</h2>

     <form name="myform" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();" method="get">


             <select name="select"  size="12" style = "width: 150px">

<%
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/itemsdb ";
    String user = "admin";
    String password = "admin";
    String Line;
    Connection Con = null;
    Statement Stmt = null;

    ResultSet RS = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
        Con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Stmt =  Con.createStatement();
        Stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ItemName FROM items");
        RS = Stmt.getResultSet();

        while(RS.next()){%>

                <Option value="<%=RS.getString("ItemName")%>">
                    <%=RS.getString("ItemName")%>
                </Option>
                </select>

             <input type="submit" value="Remove" onclick="document.pressed = this.value">
            <input type="submit" value="Display" onclick="document.pressed = this.value">
          </form>
                <form action="Add_Item.jsp" method ="get" >
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>

        <%

        }
        RS.close();
  Stmt.close();
  Con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception cnfe){
        System.err.println("Exception: "+cnfe);
    }

%>


</body>
</html>
```

I want to view data in a dropdown list in the jsp page but it seems that it's not working and I don't know what's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a MVC-Application? I mean, its maybe better to load the data in a dao return them via controller to a view. So you can debug whats wrong.
I made it so:
DAO

```
public List<String> getCiid(String eingabe)
{

    String tmp = new String("SELECT inst_ciid FROM T_INSTANCE WHERE inst_ciid like '%"+eingabe.toUpperCase()+"%'");
    Query query = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(tmp);

    List liste = query.list();

    return liste;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCiid", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getCiid(HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) 
{
    String jsonResponse = null;

    List<String> liste = instanzDao.getCiid(params.get("term"));  
    jsonResponse = new Gson().toJson(liste);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    try 
    {
        response.getOutputStream().print(jsonResponse);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

view:

```
$( "#ciid" ).autocomplete({
      source: "getCiid",
      minLength: 3,
      select: function( event, ui ) {

       // whatever you want
      }
}); 
<td>
                    <label for="ciid"> CIID: </label>
                    <form:input path="instanceCiid" id="ciid" />
                </td>
```